# How to get rid of the *Personal File Sharing* bar in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome3, debian, bluetooth

I just moved from Ubuntu to Debian Wheezy and I thought I'd be finally free of all the unnecessary clutter. I guess I was wrong. Here is the situation:

In the `Downloads` folder, Nautilus displays the following message:

> Personal File Sharing
>
> *You can receive files over Bluetooth into this folder*

[image]

I'd really like that to go away. My PC is not bluetooth-enabled, and even if it were, I'd figure out a way to share my files without the constant reminder. But I digress. Here's what I've tried so far:

- The launch preferences dialog doesn't seem to make the notification go away, even when I enable sharing over the non-existent bluetooth device
- Nautilus' `Preferences` dialog doesn't present a relevant option
- Removing the `bluez` package via `synaptic` threatens to take the entire Gnome desktop with it. Same with trying to remove `gedit` or, indeed, `nautilus`. I feel like having Jules Winnfield over my head saying "I dare you. I *double* dare you".

In my previous Ubuntu installation I managed to remove bluetooth-related packages by switching to Thunar (and getting rid of the entire Unity family). This time I'd like to keep Nautilus if possible. The presence of a bluetooth package is something I  can deal with later, what I'm worried about is the notification. Is there any way to make it go away?

---

#### Update:

I decided to manually remove dependencies from the .deb files. Using [this](https://geekwentfreak-raviteja.rhcloud.com/blog/2012/10/10/modify-dependencies-addremove-files-of-debian-deb-package/) for guidance, I removed pretty much all but the most fundamental packages (such as X11 or sound packages) from `gnome`, `gnome-core` and `task-gnome-desktop`. I must have missed something though because removing unwanted packages such as bluetooth still wanted to take away Gnome.

---

#### Update 2:

It turns out neither `gnome` nor `gnome-core` are essential to the system. In fact, from what I can tell, their only job is to provide dependencies and recommendations. I went ahead and purged them. This cased aptitude to see a bunch of useful packages as "no longer needed" and required to set the "manual install" flag on the ones I wanted - fair enough. A happy side-effect, bluetooth-related packages are gone.

I did get rid of `nautilus-share` though as @grawity suggested.  <strike>This did not affect the notification at all. The problem remains</strike>. After a re-login, the offending area had vanished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is either `nautilus-share` or `gnome-user-share`.

Comment: It's `gnome-user-share` in my case, but it too wants to take away the `gnome` and `gnome-core` packages.

Comment: The `task-gnome-desktop` and `gnome` are just meta-packages.. you can safely remove them...  They'll packages the meta-package depends on will show up under "Installed (auto removeable)", so **don't run** `apt-get autoremove` or just mark them as nolonger not-auto-installed in synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

I browsed around the Gnome settings and discovered the following:

Go to "Settings" → "Bluetooth network" → "Turn off"

Voilà! That blue eye-popping offer disappeared immediately.

Comment: Well, thank you for the edition @G-Man Looks somewhat better.